# How to install ZBar for 64-bit Windows and Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, 64-bit, zbar

I'm trying to use the zbar library with Python 2.7 and Windows 64-bit, but there are no readily made .exe installations.

I'm fairly new to "making the build" myself.  What are the steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not found for 64-bit but you can run Python 2.7 32-bit on a 64-bit machine and use the installer found here.

http://www.4shared.com/file/Zg8oJ9-g/zbar-010win32-py27_2.html

Comment: Here is a mirror link, from a more credible source: https://github.com/jacobvalenta/zbar-py27-msi/blob/master/zbar-0.10.win32-py2.7_2.msi

Comment: Jacob's file works and seems legit. Would be nice if there were an official zbar file like this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm aware this does not directly answer the question, but if you run into insurmountable problems with the build process on Windows then you may wish to look at simply running Zbar command line calls via subprocess (http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

At the very basic level you can do something such as:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output(["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ZBar\\bin\\zbarimg","-q",     "E:\path-to-files\QR_image.png"])
```

Depending on your situation, it might beat downloading an installer from a potentially questionable site.